# python how to convert blob to string

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, encryption, blob

Using amazon KMS to encrypt passwords

```
response = self.kms_client.encrypt(
            KeyId = key_id,
            Plaintext = '1234'
        )
```

response is

```
{u'CiphertextBlob': '
 �"����@��^j~>{���b�3�->�i,,,�J�5{`>��BP�V��h�Fe��9'}
```

I want to save the encrypted text to file in order to 
1. read encrypted text 
2. send to amazon to decrypt it .

Was Unable to find a method to do so in python .

Comment: Have you looked through an ORM's source code for help like Django or Flask?

Comment: @Obj3ctiv3_C_88 not following you , I looked online for a python solution and didn't find any

Comment: It won't be easy to find but Django is an ORM which does work with Blob's so the answer is somewhere in there. I've never done something of this nature but an existing ORM is a great start https://github.com/django/django/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=blob

Answer (score 2):

Managed to do so using `base64.b64encode` and `b64decode`

```
    plain_text = '1111'
    encrypted_blob = data_protector.encrypt_text(plain_text)
    encrypted_text = base64.b64encode(encrypted_blob)
    encrypted_blob = base64.b64decode(encrypted_text)
    decrypted_text = data_protector.decrypt_text(encrypted_blob) #  decrypted_text = '111'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I am getting this error - "NameError: name 'data_protector' is not defined". How can I get rid of it?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have that code anymore and I don't remember